# Opening Instagram app from a link on iOS

Tags: ios, instagram

I am providing a feed which is consumed by both desktop and mobile apps which contains links to images, users, and tags on Instagram. When these links are clicked on iOS, I want them to open in the Instagram app.

Currently if I have a link like this:
https://www.instagram.com/p/BK8f1rigadE/

If I click it in iOS, the Instagram app *does open*, just briefly. It then seems to launch Safari to the page, which includes an "open in app" link to open it back up in the app. That link uses the "[instagram://](https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/)" protocol to trigger the app to open. I'm aware of that method, but that's not what I'm after.

I'm on iOS 10 with the latest Instagram app. I feel like this used to work, so I'm wondering if it's just a bug in iOS or Instagram that will be fixed eventually.

Links to twitter.com open properly in the Twitter app... that's the kind of behavior I'm after.

Answer (score 6):

I found a service called [URL Genius](http://app.urlgeni.us/) (via [this blog post](https://pureoxygenlabs.com/increase-engagement-and-followers-on-instagram-create-links-that-can-detect-the-instagram-mobile-app-for-ios-or-android/)) that solves this exact problem, and provides click metrics, too.

I don't like relying on an external service for such an important link, but it's easy, works well, and the basic service is free. I will probably set a reminder for myself to check that this still works every month or so...

Answer (score 4):

Links like this work to open the app:
`instagram://media?id=1346423547953773636_401375631`

However I want a regular http link, which opens a browser on desktop, and the app on mobile. Not sure if it exists.

Comment: Hi, @Josh how to get "id", which you have written here from my library.

Answer (score 1):

From my knowledge, the only supported links into Instagram are described [here](https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/)

I'm not sure what the link you're attempting to use represents: `/p/id_here` seems like a post? You likely need to use:

`https://www.instagram.com/media?id=id_here`

The documentation I linked shows the "deeplink" approach (`instagram://`) which I understand you're avoiding, but the same paths should work through the `Universal Link` approach, at least from my experience.

Comment: What's a Universal Link? This doesn't do it. https://www.instagram.com/media?id=BK8f1rigadE

Comment: Universal links: https://developer.apple.com/ios/universal-links/   how are you generating that ID? Not sure what methodology you're using to get that media ID.

Comment: It's just a media ID from their API. If you go to a user page like instagram.com/endquote and click an image, you'll end up at a URL with that ID.

Comment: I'm guessing Facebook and Instagram don't support universal links, but rather, you *have* to use URL with their custom URL scheme (`facebook` or `instagram`? Anyone have success with Universal links?

Comment: I have a video in my library, I have a url, how to get a media id ?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. For me was solved by simply uninstalling and reinstalling the problematic app.

(Instagram 171.0 - iOS 14.3 - iPhone 11 Pro)

Answer (score 0):

On iOS you must first add the `instagram` url scheme in the **LSApplicationQueriesSchemes** key of the `info.plist` file:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>    
    <string>instagram</string> 
</array>
```

then you can open the url of the post using the link:

`instagram://media?id=POST_MEDIA_ID`

POST_MEDIA_ID can be found by looking at the page source, you will find a tag like this:

```
<meta property="al:ios:url" content="instagram://media?id=POST_MEDIA_ID"/>
```

Obviously, the Instagram app must be installed on the device, otherwise the link will not work.