# Firebase In-app messaging opens the URL with link only once in swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-in-app-messaging

I have a strange problem with firebase in-app message for iOS in swift.

the message is getting displayed during the launch as expected,i was sending a URL with the button action to launch it in the browser in the app.

unfortunately the link doesnt get opened.

so i tried sending a dynamic link from firebase with the button action,then i tried sending in-app message with the new instance id that generated in the console.

the dynamic link only opens the browser with the expected link only for the first time .. in rest of all scenarios it just shows the message as usual and button doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

To work on iOS you must first add the url scheme in the **LSApplicationQueriesSchemes** key of the `info.plist` file.

Here you can see an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72059449/5811628